# Finding string position (index) in another string for each row of a data.frame

Tags: r, string

In my data.frame, I have two columns with text (say, str1 and str2). I want to add a column that indicates the position of str2 in str1 for each row.

An example for the data.frame:

```
dt <- data.frame(str1 = c('ab/some words,cd/some words', 
'cd/some words,ab/some words', 'ab/some words,cd/some words', 'ef/some 
words,ab/some words'), str2 = c('ab', 'cd', 'cd', 'ef'))
```

I want to add a column that indicates the position of str2 in str1 for each row.

This doesn't work:

```
dt$str2.pos <- regexpr(dt$str2, dt$str1)
```

I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
                         str1 str2 str2.pos
1 ab/some words,cd/some words   ab        1
2 cd/some words,ab/some words   cd        1
3 ab/some words,cd/some words   cd       15
4 ef/some words,ab/some words   ef        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do

```
dt$str2.pos <- diag(sapply(dt$str2, function(x) regexpr(x, dt$str1)))
dt$str2.pos
#[1]  1  1 15  1
```

---

If we are doing this for corresponding rows, then use `mapply/Map`

```
mapply(regexpr, dt$str2, dt$str1)
#[1]  1  1 15  1
```